# Windows.Networking.Proximity C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dll

I want to add "Windows.Networking.Proximity"  Namespace to C# project. 
How can I add that? That is not available in the project.

When I'm adding the reference attached error coming. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: *Do I need to add any reference* -> Yeah obviously isn't it?

Comment: What is the reference I need to add?

Comment: U can check here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.proximity and download from a ton of DLL site.

Comment: According to the above site, it is available in two assemblies namely *Windows.Networking.Proximity.dll, Windows.dll*. You can refer to any of them...

Comment: Where can I get those DLLs

Comment: Bear in mind, Windows.Networking.Proximity is a *UWP* namespace and assembly. What type of project are you trying to pull this reference into?

Comment: I'm using WPF application in VS 2015.